# Склонения числительных

Tags: числительные

Как правильно? С шестью или с шестьми? Творительный падеж

Comment: В учебнике русского языка это есть.Учитесь прилежно.

Answer (score 2):

С шестью нулями, шестью столами

Comment: Спасибо, я конечно знала, но совсем запуталась ... а когда мы используем шестьми или такого слова нет?

Comment: Это просторечие, а возможно, диалектизм

Answer (score 1):

числительное шесть склоняется по третьему типу склонения существительных. Значит, как слово степь, ночь. С наступающим Новым годом!